# How to add GeoSlick library in my Playframework scala Application

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, postgis

How to add [GeoSlick library](https://github.com/ahinz/GeoSlick) in my Playframework scala Application. I need to use postgres database postGIS functions in my model. Is it possible to add as jar file? How to convert this project as jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many SBT projects (which GeoSlick obviously is, because it has the typical SBT files like build.sbt) the following procedure gets you an jar you can import in your project.

1. Clone the GIT repository with `git clone https://github.com/ahinz/GeoSlick`
2. Move into the directory and run `sbt`. This will download all dependencies defined in the project definitions.
3. If everything was downloaded correctly, type into the sbt shell `package` and enter.

This last step will compile a SNAPSHOT-jar file and puts it into the directory *target/scala-2.10/*

I did this for the project you named and it worked fine, producing a file *geoslick_2.10-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar*.

Comment: Is it any other way to use PostGis function without using GeoSlick library? Already I am using postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar and slick.

Comment: Why don't you use GeoSlick? Seems to me like a library providing PostGis functionality...?

Comment: I used geometry functions in slick plain query without using GeoSlick library.It works fine.